# What's the correct command to revert my files in git?

Tags: git

I'm new to git.

I'm working on a project, the files under the project directory are commited, and I just added many files by mistake. They are neither added to git nor commit.

Now I want removed them, so I try:

```
git revert HEAD
```

But they are still there, and messages are:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c git revert HEAD
Finished one revert.
error: Terminal is dumb, but EDITOR unset
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

(I'm using windows and gvim)

What's the correct command?

Comment: `git revert` is used to revert commits. `git reset` or, in this case, `git clean`, are used to revert uncommited changes.

Comment: @Lajnold: `git reset` resets changes in the *index* (or if using `--hard`, the entire index and work tree) - to check out the original version of given paths, you use `git checkout`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `git clean -f` to remove all untracked files.